# Gear motor fine until it touches other gear

Tags: animation, physics, constraints, rigidbody

I'm trying to create a planetary gear system, [following the tutorial on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-SPCvXHys0), following everything to a tee.

I have finished making the sun, planet, and ring gear, yet once the sun moves and touches the planet, all animations jam up.

So I remove the ring gear and 2 planets to leave me with 1 sun and 1 planet for simplicity sake. Then I go another step and I remove the planet, and the sun rotates again freely.

When I reintroduce the planet, the sun will spin slowly fine. Then it touches the planet and jams.

Would anyone know what causes this issue?

[Link to my file on Youtube](https://youtu.be/_rxy2Zmk8xU).

Comment: Please add your blend file, so we can check it out

Comment: Hi! it's hard to understand your problem without any reference. You should add screenshots or a blend file to make sure people can understand your problem and also most of the people here are not patient enough to go through the entire tutorial and understand your problem.

Comment: try solving the problem by verifying your setup with the blend file shared in the youtube video description. 
And if you can't figure it out then edit your question by adding more details and your blend file :D

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. I've just uploaded the fie unto Youtube. The first clip is the whole planetary gear. The 2nd clip shows me simplifying everything down to just the sun and planet to see if the mechanics will work.

Comment: link is: https://youtu.be/_rxy2Zmk8xU

Comment: As Chris asked - blend file would be probably needed ... in meantime check "Face orientation" (Normals direction) of those objects.

Comment: How do I upload the blend file on this forum?

Comment: Use https://blend-exchange.com and copy-paste given code to your Question via edit. Your Q would be probably closed, external links as main source of informations are not allowed, they are not permanent. Please add some descriptive image (or animated gif) to illustrate issue. Even you solve it, this site is knowledge base, so others can learn from your issues. Thank you keep this site organised.

Answer (score 1):

I checked out the face orientation and saw the values were messing up the gears. I played around with the pattern and got it all working now!

[image]

Comment: You'r welcome. Just same as my comment above ... I edited answer here for you so it better fits to BSE guidelines. Please do similar for your Q. Thank you ... BTW it should be all blue :)

Comment: Okay thanks again! Blue! And questions to the blend-exchange.com. WIll do!